# amp-carousel remove white margins around amp-img?

Tags: amp-html

I am using amp-carousel to display amp-img. My issue is that the carousel leaves two white margins left and right of the image, whereas it does not do it with other elements ?

See playground here :

https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-carousel%2Fsource%2F

[image]

How to remove the white margins around the image ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Which browser do you use? I can't reproduce it in Safari or Chrome.

Comment: I use Chrome latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here to override the default margin :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/amphtml-discuss/z2BUCvIahDI/1oGDyxaYCgAJ;context-place=forum/amphtml-discuss